# SQL - GROUP BY Total Hours per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following data

```
Task | Start Time        | End Time
A    | 2/24/2020 1:00 PM | 2/24/2020 2:00 PM
B    | 2/24/2020 3:00 PM | 2/24/2020 5:00 PM
A    | 2/25/2020 1:00 PM | 2/25/2020 2:00 PM
B    | 2/25/2020 3:00 PM | 2/25/2020 6:00 PM
```

Is it possible to write a query that returns the total number of hours in a task per day based from start time and end time values? Something like:

```
Task | 2-21 | 2-22 | 2-23 | 2-24 | 2-25 | 2-26 | 2-27
A    |  0       0        0     1    | 1    0     0
B    |  0       0        0     2    | 3    0     0
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I am planning to create a stored procedure wherein there are two inputs that will serve as a fixed range for the data (7-day range) and will automatically input 0 if said date is not available on the table.

Comment: With Dynamic SQL, yes. I suggest that if you don't know what you're doing with that, you *don't* go down that path. Instead have 1 row per date. To be honest, you're likely better off doing that anyway and having your reporting/presentation layer doing the pivoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to transpose a dynamic amount of columns you should check out this [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/). It talks about different methods and their performance.
XML or dynamic SQL is probably what you're looking for.

```
select
  task,
  wdate = cast(start_time as date),
  total_hours = sum(datediff(HOUR, start_time, end_time))
into #t
from tasks
group by task, cast(start_time as date)


DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                            ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[wdate])
                     FROM #t c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
          
SET @query = 'SELECT
                [task], ' + @cols + '
              from (
                SELECT
                  [task],
                  [total_hours] AS [amount],
                  [wdate] AS [category]
                FROM #t
              ) x pivot (SUM(amount) for category in (' + @cols + ')) p';

EXECUTE (@query);
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I am planning to have data released on a fixed 7-day column wherein the start date range and the end date range will be provided as parameter prior to releasing the data and for those dates that are not present in the main table, their value will be 0.

Comment: but I will be accepting this answer for flexibility (dynamic columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what days you'll need as columns you could use a pivot. But if you don't know the columns ahead of time you'll need to use some sort of dynamic SQL as Larnu has suggested.

Here is an example if you knew that you only had the 2 days in your example:

This syntax is for Snowflake but it would be similar to sql-server

```sql
select *
from (
         select
             task,
             date_trunc('day', start_time)                     day,
             datediff('hours', min(start_time), max(end_time)) diff
         from test_table
         group by task, day
         order by day
     )
         pivot (sum(diff) for day in ('2020-02-24', '2020-02-25')) as p
```

Comment: I am planning to create a stored procedure wherein there are two inputs that will serve as a fixed range for the data (7-day range) and will automatically input 0 if said date is not available on the table.